# Time of evaluation of condition (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, evaluation

I'm interested at what point of time a condition in an if/else statement gets evaluated.

Imagine there's the following sample:

```
if (complex condition 1) {
  do something
}
else if (complex condition 2) {
  do something else
}
else if (complex condition 3) {
  do something else
}
else {
  do anything
}
```

What I want to know is: does each of the complex conditions get check on ahead of time, and the interpreter just execudes the codepart of the condition that is true, or does it start with the first condition when it comes to it and only evaluates the second condition when the first one is false?

I'm interested in regards to make some optimizations for low-end mobile devices.

Comment: The second is only evaluated if the first is false. I'm not sure what you mean by "complex condition", but even with something simple like `if(x || y)` if x is true y won't be evaluated. You can test this for yourself by putting a function call in the condition and calling console.log() within the function.

Comment: well for performance reasons I want to avoid that low-end mobile devices have to or will evaluate any of those complex conditions ahead of time (= unless they are really needed).

Comment: JavaScript evaluates all code only "when it gets there".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition clause of an `if` statement is evaluated when the `if` statement is reached in the flow of execution. In your example, if the first condition is `true`, then *none* of the other conditions will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

As "Short-circuit_evaluation" says: "...the second argument is executed or evaluated only if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression."

The execution will stop when reach a true statement.

Comment: The term "short-circuit" refers to evaluations of Boolean expressions using `&&` and `||`, not nested `if` statements.